# Problem with border radius rounded corners

Tags: css

I have a div with a solid border and rounded corners defined in CSS, but looking at it in Chrome or FF renders the following (screenshot):

[image: Rounded Corner]

I can't figure out why the solid border is not visible along the rounded corner edges? Here is the associated CSS:

```
  div.evalframe {
   font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
   margin: 20px 0 0 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 635px;
   border: 1px solid #666666;
   background-color: #f4f4f4;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
   border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: apparently no problem with the css. Can you link some live example at jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you might have an  tag or some other tag inside this div that draws over the corners.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I had a div inside this div, which specified the same background-color #f4f4f4, which was not needed. As soon as I removed the background-color from the inner div, all worked fine. Thanks!