# Image cover fit hides border corner of container

Tags: python, css, border, border-radius, flet

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357835/problem-with-border-radius-rounded-corners) but I'm not sure how I can implement it in Flet. I need Result-1's fit but Result-2's border.

My code:

```py
    def build(self):
        return ft.Container(
            ft.Image(
                src=self.imgPath, 
                fit=ft.ImageFit.COVER,
            ), 
            width=250, 
            height=250, 
            border_radius=ft.border_radius.all(20), 
            border = ft.border.all(2, 'grey'),
            on_hover=self.mouse_hover,
        )
```

Result:

[image]

Altered code:

```py
    def build(self):
        return ft.Container(
            ft.Image(
                src=self.imgPath, 
                # fit=ft.ImageFit.COVER,
            ), 
            width=250, 
            height=250, 
            border_radius=ft.border_radius.all(20), 
            border = ft.border.all(2, 'grey'),
            on_hover=self.mouse_hover,
        )
```

Result:

[image]